Embed Google Photos Upload in iFrame
I have a public (e.g. no sign-in permissions required) Google Photo gallery (https://photos.google.com/u/1/share/AF1QipMprZKlgpg-x5WjqQYOP95qV6Db9gBAw2o5gDWQDkayqFx0o0EdPXHqnlwdVsuldw) and I am trying to embed it in an iFrame.
Although the URL itself looks like this:

The iFrame embed looks like this in the same browser:

Here is my HTML:
<iframe src="https://photos.google.com/u/1/share/AF1QipMprZKlgpg-x5WjqQYOP95qV6Db9gBAw2o5gDWQDkayqFx0o0EdPXHqnlwdVsuldw" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>


Google probably doesn't want you iframing the page.
